# upload file ftp client commons net ftp 3.6 / 3.1 / 2.2

Tags: java, android, ftp

Hi this is the first post form me and sorry for my basic english, i have a problem with this action i try to trasfer a file from my phone to server HTTP in a specifics directory. I must take a storage/Download because another app save the file in this directory and i can't modifiy this path.

```
package com.example.mufas.bookonline;`

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.net.SocketException;

import es.dmoral.toasty.Toasty;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void deleteFile(View view) {


        File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

        File file = new File(path, "esempio.txt");

        if (path.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Il file " + path + " esiste");
            file.delete();
            System.out.println("Il file " + path + " è stato eliminato");
            Toasty.success(getApplication(), "File elimininato", Toast.LENGTH_LONG, true).show();
        }
        // Make sure the Pictures directory exists.
        path.mkdirs();

    }

    public void newFile(View view) {

//          String path = "/Pictures/html.txt";

        File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

        try {
//         File file = new File(getFilesDir(),path);
            File file = new File(path, "esempio.txt");
            Toasty.success(getApplication(), "File Creato", Toast.LENGTH_LONG, true).show();
            if (file.exists()) {
                Toasty.success(getApplication(), "Il file è gia stato creato", Toast.LENGTH_LONG, true).show();
                System.out.println("Il file " + path + " esiste");
            } else if (file.createNewFile()) {
                System.out.println("Il file " + path + " è stato creato");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Il file " + path + " non può essere creato");
            }

            // Make sure the Download directory exists.
            path.mkdirs();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void trasferisciFile(View view) {

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

            FTPClient mFTP = new FTPClient();


          File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                  Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

 //               File path = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

                        // Connect to FTP Server
                        mFTP.connect("<host>", 21);
                        mFTP.login("<user>", "<password>");
                        //mFTP.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                        mFTP.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE, FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                        mFTP.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                        mFTP.enterLocalPassiveMode();


                        // Prepare file to be uploaded to FTP Server

                        File file = new File(path, "esempio.txt");

//                    System.out.println(" sono pronto a trasferire da questo percorso" + path + file);

                        FileInputStream ifile = new FileInputStream(file);

                    // Upload file to FTP Server
                    mFTP.storeFile("online", ifile);

                    mFTP.disconnect();

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toasty.success(getApplication(), "Il file è stato trasferito", Toast.LENGTH_LONG, true).show();
                        }
                    });

                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();


    }

} // fine classe main
```

and this is my manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mufas.bookonline">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:isolatedProcess="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In logat i haven't error and the app rensponde me "Transfer Success" i am using Android Studio and device is Smasung galaxy tab 3 android 6.0 what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: what you want achieve? elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but i send the post and now i can't edit its. The problem is with the file is not present in the remote directory to the end of the process i try to installed the app in the phone but  without result.  Sorry for the duplicate post